# Passport login with React Router only working on second click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios, passport.js

We're trying to integrate Passport authentication with out React app, and we're using React Router.

On the first submission of correct user credentials, the server receives the post, adds a session to our database, and seems to send a response, but the client doesn't update. The username and password show up in the url as a query string. Then when we resend the credentials without removing the query string from the url, the client is able to receive the response from the server.

In other words, if we don't refresh before submitting the login info again, it works.

This is the click handler that our form utilizes:

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    return axios.post('/login', { username, password })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        const { message } = data;
        if (message === 'success') {
          const { user } = data;
          setUserId(user.id);
          setUser(user);
        }
        setAuthStatus(message);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  };
```

This is our server route that is hit on every post request:

```
loginRouter.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('stop');
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    const { invalidPassword } = info || false;
    if (err) {
      return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.send({ message: 'invalidUser' });
    }

    if (invalidPassword) {
      return res.send({ message: 'invalidPassword' });
    }
    req.login(user, loginErr => {
      if (loginErr) {
        return next(loginErr);
      }
      return res.send({ user, message: 'success' });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

This is our Passport Local Strategy that uses Sequelize:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  (username, password, cb) => {
    User.findOne({ where: { username } })
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          return cb(null, false);
        }
        if (validPassword(password, user.hash, user.salt)) {
          return cb(null, user);
        }
        return cb(null, false, { invalidPassword: true });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        cb(err);
      });
  },
));
```

Having trouble debugging this... We suspect the error is on the client side and may have to do with React-Router. We are using React-Router and Passport for the first time on this project.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you sure you don't miss `.then(resp => resp.json())` before `.then(({ data }) =>`?

Answer (score 0):

Welp... All we were missing was event as a parameter in handleClick and event.preventDefault().